# How does this CheckDraw method work for TicTacToe- C++

Tags: c++, class, methods, tic-tac-toe

I have to determine how exactly the CheckDraw method works but after reviewing the code for hours, I still haven't figured out anything.

```
bool CheckDraw(bool GameOver)
{
   int n = 1;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int counter = 0;

   for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
      for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
         if(table[i][j] == '0'+n)
            counter++;
      n++;
   }
   if( counter < 1 )
   {
      cout << "It's a draw!\n\n";
      GameOver = true;
   }
   return GameOver;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it does work? What is the contents of `table`? Have you tried using a debugger? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Note that I think the method probably doesn't actually check for a draw, it probably checks whether there are any possible moves available and is just incorrectly named (presumably it is preceded by a call to a method which checks for a winner so effectively by checking for no remaining moves it is effectively checking for a draw)

Comment: The code doesn't make a lot of sense. `'0'+n` and `n++` are rather suspect.

Comment: It's considered a draw if the board does not contain `'1'` in the first row, `'2'` in the second, or `'3'` in the third. This seems like a pretty odd representation of a tictactoe board. (And the parameter is a mystery.)

Comment: @AlanBirtles can you expound your 2nd comment?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yeah I was confused at first also but the first time it was used in the code, there was a comment saying that "cast n to a character", it then made sense but there were no signs of casting in the code but apparently it works...

Comment: the table shows like this:
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code is buggy, `n` is only incremented for each row so  it is checking for `1|1|1 2|2|2 3|3|3` instead of `1|2|3 4|5|6 7|8|9`. It would be much simpler to just check for a cell that is not `X` or `O`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found out how it works...So there's this method in the code where if the player enters a number, that number is replaced with the character assigned to a player (X or O). So this part of the code:

```
for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
     if(table[i][j] == '0'+n)
```

scans through the board for numbers that have not been changed to X or O.

The code below the nested loops starting from "counter++" verifies the number of times the nested loop looped. The nested loop should continue to loop for 3 times, so the counter variable should also increment 2 times and if it looped less than 1 then the game is considered a draw.

This is how I think it should work, if I omitted any mistake, feel free to correct me

Huge thanks to @AlanBirtles for his comment, I suddenly got an idea.